# Scikit Learn TfidfVectorizer : How to get top n terms with highest tf-idf score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk, tf-idf

I am working on keyword extraction problem. Consider the very general case

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, stop_words='english')

t = """Two Travellers, walking in the noonday sun, sought the shade of a widespreading tree to rest. As they lay looking up among the pleasant leaves, they saw that it was a Plane Tree.

"How useless is the Plane!" said one of them. "It bears no fruit whatever, and only serves to litter the ground with leaves."

"Ungrateful creatures!" said a voice from the Plane Tree. "You lie here in my cooling shade, and yet you say I am useless! Thus ungratefully, O Jupiter, do men receive their blessings!"

Our best blessings are often the least appreciated."""

tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(t.split(" "))
str = 'tree cat travellers fruit jupiter'
response = tfidf.transform([str])
feature_names = tfidf.get_feature_names()

for col in response.nonzero()[1]:
    print(feature_names[col], ' - ', response[0, col])
```

and this gives me

```
  (0, 28)   0.443509712811
  (0, 27)   0.517461475101
  (0, 8)    0.517461475101
  (0, 6)    0.517461475101
tree  -  0.443509712811
travellers  -  0.517461475101
jupiter  -  0.517461475101
fruit  -  0.517461475101
```

which is good. For any new document that comes in, is there a way to get the top n terms with the highest tfidf score?

Comment: You probably shouldn't overwrite the Python datatype str.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to do a little bit of a song and dance to get the matrices as numpy arrays instead, but this should do what you're looking for:

```
feature_array = np.array(tfidf.get_feature_names())
tfidf_sorting = np.argsort(response.toarray()).flatten()[::-1]

n = 3
top_n = feature_array[tfidf_sorting][:n]
```

This gives me:

```
array([u'fruit', u'travellers', u'jupiter'], 
  dtype='<U13')
```

The `argsort` call is really the useful one, [here are the docs for it](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html). We have to do `[::-1]` because `argsort` only supports sorting small to large. We call `flatten` to reduce the dimensions to 1d so that the sorted indices can be used to index the 1d feature array. Note that including the call to `flatten` will only work if you're testing one document at at time.

Also, on another note, did you mean something like `tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(t.split("\n\n"))`? Otherwise, each term in the multiline string is being treated as a "document". Using `\n\n` instead means that we are actually looking at 4 documents (one for each line), which makes more sense when you think about tfidf.

Comment: How would I achieve that by using DictVectorizer + TfidfTransformer?

Comment: What if we want to list top n terms for each class not for each document? I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833987/listing-top-n-features-in-each-class-using-sklearn-and-tf-idf-values) but no response yet!

Comment: What do you mean, "for each class". Say you have documents labeled "A" and documents labeled "B". You could either: (1) calculate "TF-ICF", which gives you the term frequency-inverse class frequency. Do that just by concatenating all of the documents of a class into a single string and doing the normal tfidf process. (2) Alternatively, you could calculate average TFIDF, by adding the class as a column to the TFIDF, creating a pandas dataframe, and then doing `tfidf_dataframe.groupby('class_name').mean()`.

Comment: Strangely, The last line gives memory errors , while replacing it to `top_n = feature_array[tfidf_sorting[:n]]` it doesn't .

Comment: @Pedram, I asked the same question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703244/find-top-n-in-terms-of-tf-idf-score-vocabulary-per-class) for per class you mention it at your comment above. Do you have an answer to it?

Comment: By the way, @hume this line `tfidf_sorting = np.argsort(response.toarray()).flatten()[::-1]` gives me a memory error which must be because my tf-idf matrix is too big. So I guess that I could do this in batches?

Comment: I haven't looked into this at all, but casting tfidf.get_feature_names() as an numpy.array uses massively more memory than the default Python list. My 300mb TFIDF model turns into 4+ Gb in RAM when I call numpy.array on get_feature_names(), whereas simply using feature_array = tfidf.get_feature_names() works fine and uses very little RAM.

Comment: @Atlas feature_array = tfidf.get_feature_names() worked for me

Answer (score 13):

Solution using sparse matrix itself (without `.toarray()`)!

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
corpus = [
    'I would like to check this document',
    'How about one more document',
    'Aim is to capture the key words from the corpus',
    'frequency of words in a document is called term frequency'
]

X = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus)
feature_names = np.array(tfidf.get_feature_names())


new_doc = ['can key words in this new document be identified?',
           'idf is the inverse document frequency caculcated for each of the words']
responses = tfidf.transform(new_doc)


def get_top_tf_idf_words(response, top_n=2):
    sorted_nzs = np.argsort(response.data)[:-(top_n+1):-1]
    return feature_names[response.indices[sorted_nzs]]
  
print([get_top_tf_idf_words(response,2) for response in responses])

#[array(['key', 'words'], dtype='<U9'),
 array(['frequency', 'words'], dtype='<U9')]
```

Comment: It returns the repetitive words also, When I am trying to use these top n words as my vocabulary in tfidfvectorizer again, it throws and value error with as there are duplicate words in vocab. How will I get top n unique words?

Comment: Interesting. I am using `get_feature_names()` to get the `feature_names`, hence there should not be any duplicates returned by `get_top_tf_idf_words`. Can you post a new question, with a reproducible example and tag me?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a **quick code** for that:
(`documents` is a list)

```
def get_tfidf_top_features(documents,n_top=10):
  tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2,  stop_words='english')
  tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
  importance = np.argsort(np.asarray(tfidf.sum(axis=0)).ravel())[::-1]
  tfidf_feature_names = np.array(tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
  return tfidf_feature_names[importance[:n_top]]
```

Comment: There is a typo in the second line. The first character "t" is missing.

Comment: no_features is missing variable.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. Fixed.